# Init PagingQueryProvider from query in SQL file

Tags: sql, mysql, spring-batch

I want my spring batch to read data from my database. Therefore I create an ItemReader and set it with a PagingQueryProvider. My problem is that **the query used to fetch the data is stored in a SQL file** (because it is complex), so **how do I init the PagingQueryProvider from this SQL file**, instead of the more common way to write the query manually with java strings ?

What I have :

```java
MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
queryProvider.setSelectClause("select *") // select clause
queryProvider.setFromClause("from stuff") // from clause
// more clauses if needed
```

What I would like :

```java
MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
queryProvider.setFromFile("path/to/my/file.sql")
```

FYI chat GPT gave me this solution, which would probabyl work but which is terrible (basically parsing the .sql file myself to init the MySqlPagingQueryProvider accordingly)

```java
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.orm.JpaNativeQueryProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.orm.MySqlPagingQueryProvider;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class CustomPagingQueryProvider {

    public static MySqlPagingQueryProvider fromFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
        // Read the contents of the SQL file
        String sql = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));

        // Set up the query provider
        MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
        queryProvider.setSelectClause("select *"); // You may need to adjust this if your SQL file already includes the select clause
        queryProvider.setFromClause(sql);

        // You can set other properties of the query provider here if needed

        return queryProvider;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Provide the path to your SQL file
            MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = fromFile("path/to/your/file.sql");
            // Now you can use this query provider in your Spring Batch job configuration
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it produce an error?  What is wrong with reading the file to get the data you need?

Comment: If you are talking about the "What I would like" part, the method "queryProvider.setFromFile" does not exist, but I wish it did. If you are talking about the "chat GPT" part, then as you can guess from my opinion of this code, I did not test it. If I have to write the SQL in a file and then parse this file myself, it seems a bit stupid in comparison to directly writting the SQL in java strings (which I don't want to because it is terrible for readability and maintenabilty). But I can feel that in the end I will have to parse it myself. My need is so basic, how is there no method for it?

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, create it perhaps and work around the issue?  If the value doesn't change does it need to be the actual read the  SQL each time, and couldn't it just be hard coded or read just a normal text file with the values for simplicity sake?  And if the value does change then you will need to parse the values.

Comment: You did not get the issue. The problem is that I do have a SQL file with a select query, and I want to communicate this query to the PagingQueryProvider or ANY similar provider, so the ItemReader can use this provider to fetch my data by actually executing the query. I think I have to read the Spring batch documentation, it can not not exist a way to do what I want to do, this is the most simple thing!